# how to convert string into integer in uiautomation?

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am extracting a value from a text field (using .value()) and then I want to add a number to it so that I can check another value with result of above combination. At present, when I am adding number to it, so its getting appended to it. For eg, if value is 55 and I am adding number 1 to it, so result is 551 instead of 56. This is because its taking is as string and then appending it, so does anybody know a method to convert string to integer in javascript for UIAutomation?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript provides the [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function for converting Strings to Integers.

```
var strNum = "3";
var num = parseInt(strNum,10);
(typeof num == "number") ? alert("Is a number"):alert("Not a Number");
```